How to supply **kwargs with an variable that has the same name as a keyword argument?
This has already been asked here, but the answers ignore that this is in the scenario where the functions are a part of a library, and therefore the user has no control over the API (outside of submitting an issue, which I will do for my case). However, I'm hoping that there may be a quick workaround to avoid waiting for an API fix.
The scenario is as as follows. I am trying to call this function, which has keyword argument format=None, and which makes an internal call (passing the **kwargs) to a function from another library, which has a keyword argument of the same name: format. I want to effectively be able to accomplish something of this sort:
FluxPoints.read(fn, format=None, kwargs={'format':'basic'})
# OR
FluxPoints.read(fn, format=None, **{'format':'basic'})

However, none of these attempts work. Is there a workaround here or can this only be fixed in the API?

When you say "makes an internal call...to a function from another library" are you making that call on your end, or is the read method doing so?

That is a tricky one. I don't think you have any way to specify a "format" and have it passed through via the kwargs, it will always get mopped up in the wrapper function. I'm going with "can only be fixed in the API".

@JRiggles The read method is doing so, see the code that is linked.

Ah I see it now  - Table is an astropy object.

You could monkeypatch astropy.table.Table.read, but it would be pretty gross.

what happens if you pass 'basic' in as the argument to format instead of None?

They do kwargs.setdefault("format", "ascii.ecsv") on L210 but there is no possible way that format will appear in kwargs, so the code looks pretty bugged to me (you only use setdefault if you don't know whether the key is present already or not).

As stated in the comments, it's tricky to handle this situation.
I'd try to monkeypatch Table.read to put format='basic' upon call, something like this:
from contextlib import contextmanager


class Table:
    @classmethod
    def read(cls, filename, **kwargs):
        print(f"Table.read: {filename=} {kwargs=}")


def read(filename, format=None, **kwargs):
    kwargs.setdefault("format", "ascii.ecsv")
    Table.read(filename, **kwargs)
    print("format inside read():", format)


@contextmanager
def patch_table_read(format):
    tr = Table.read
    Table.read = lambda filename, **kwargs: tr(filename, format=format)
    yield
    Table.read = tr


with patch_table_read(format="basic"):
    read("file.txt", format=None)

Prints:
Table.read: filename='file.txt' kwargs={'format': 'basic'}
format inside read(): None


probably want to wrap patch_table_read in a try-finally?

@chicxulub Yes, to be more correct one should use try-finally, then handle different kwargs into Table.read etc. But for brevity I omitted that.

The general problem does have a solution, but it requires upstream API changes.

How to supply **kwargs with an argument that has the same name as a positional argument?

A technique which APIs can use is to convert the positional argument(s) into positional-only argument(s). The syntax requires Python 3.8+ and is described in PEP 570.
Without positional-only:
def func(foo, **kwargs):
    print(foo, kwargs)

func("foo", foo="foo")
# TypeError: func() got multiple values for argument 'foo'

With positional-only:
def func(foo, /, **kwargs):
    print(foo, kwargs)

func("foo", foo="foo")
# foo {'foo': 'foo'}

You may want to mention this technique when creating an issue with the upstream project.
